# Группировка в MS SQL строк с полями где NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Как то можно сгруппировать это:

```
    F1     F2      F3
--------------------------
    1     null    null
    null   2      null
    null  null     3
    4     null    null
    null   5      null
    null  null     6
```

В это:

```
F1   F2   F3
----------------
 1    2    3
 4    5    6
```

Comment: Набор отсортированный?

Comment: В каждой строке заполнено только одно поле

Comment: @Developer, этого недостаточно. Почему, например, в первой строке должно быть 1 2 3, а не, скажем, 1 5 3 или 4 2 3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если у вас всего чётко по три, то примерно так.

Данные:

```
declare @data table (row_num int, F1 int, F2 int, F3 int);

insert into @data
values 
    (1, 1, null, null)
    ,(2, null, 2, null)
    ,(3, null, null, 3)
    ,(4, 4, null, null)
    ,(5, null, 5, null)
    ,(6, null, null, 6)
    ;
```

Запрос:

```
;with data
as (
    select
        rn = row_num - 1,
        *
    from @data
)
select F1 = max(F1), F2 = max(F2), F3 = max(F3)
from data
group by rn / 3;
```

Результат:

```
F1          F2          F3
----------- ----------- -----------
1           2           3
4           5           6
```

Порядок строк всё-же нужно определить - либо явно (как в примере), либо косвенно (с помощью функции `row_number() over (order by ...)`), иначе нет гарантии, что строки сгруппируются как надо.

Answer (score 0):

Если нет дополнительных ограничений, т.е. значения не отсортированы и могут быть любыми, то можно вот так в три чтения:

```
DECLARE
  @T TABLE(F1 INT, F2 INT, F3 INT)
INSERT @T VALUES
(1,null,null),
(null,2,null),
(null,null,3),
(4,null,null),
(7,5,null),
(8,null,6),
(null,null,null),
(null,null,9),
(10,null,null)


SELECT F1, F2, F3
FROM(
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY F1)N1, F1
  FROM @T
  WHERE F1 IS NOT NULL
)T1 
FULL JOIN(
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY F2)N2, F2
  FROM @T
  WHERE F2 IS NOT NULL
)T2 ON N1=N2
FULL JOIN(
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY F3)N3, F3
  FROM @T
  WHERE F3 IS NOT NULL
)T3 ON N3=ISNULL(N1,N2)

--результат:
/*
F1  F2    F3
1  2     3
4  5     6
7  NULL  9
8  NULL  NULL
10  NULL  NULL
*/
```

Если в одной строке только одно значение не NULL, то можно сгруппировать так в одно чтение:

```
DECLARE
  @T TABLE(F1 INT, F2 INT, F3 INT)
INSERT @T VALUES
(1,null,null),
(null,2,null),
(null,null,3),
(4,null,null),
(null,5,null),
(8,null,null),
(11,null,null),
(null,null,9),
(null,null,99),
(10,null,null)

SELECt GRP, F1, F2, F3
FROM(
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY [Type] ORDER BY Value)GRP
  FROM(
    SELECT
      CASE 
        WHEN F1 IS NOT NULL THEN F1
        WHEN F2 IS NOT NULL THEN F2
        WHEN F3 IS NOT NULL THEN F3
      END Value,
      CASE 
        WHEN F1 IS NOT NULL THEN 'F1'
        WHEN F2 IS NOT NULL THEN 'F2'
        WHEN F3 IS NOT NULL THEN 'F3'
      END [Type]
    FROM @T
  )T
)T PIVOT(
  MAX(Value) FOR [Type] IN (F1, F2, F3)
)pvt
--результат:
/*
GRP    F1     F2     F3
1      1      2      3
2      4      5      9
3      8      NULL   99
4      10     NULL   NULL
5      11     NULL   NULL
*/
```